# Rails - where do the model instance variables come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I come from an ASP.NET MVC background and am currently going through the following Rails tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I have created a "Post" model which contains some instance variables, but they do not seem to have been defined in the model. They must come from somewhere else. Where are they defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googled "activerecord model" and this was in the top result:

> Active Record objects don’t specify their attributes directly, but rather infer them from the table definition with which they’re linked. Adding, removing, and changing attributes and their type is done directly in the database. Any change is instantly reflected in the Active Record objects. The mapping that binds a given Active Record class to a certain database table will happen automatically in most common cases, but can be overwritten for the uncommon ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can have virtual variables that don't correlate to fields in a table/model. A common example is the 'password' and 'password_confirmation' variables used in authentication. You  have them exist temporarily until you encrypt it and save it to another field like 'encrypted_password'.

You can declare them but that's not required. You don't have to define or declare them anywhere... just start using them. Of course, they're not persistent though, so won't be saved.